# Attributes get parent field inside PXFormula

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom field I have a PXFormula attribute with a pretty simple Switch inside where I want to show the assedCD of a FixedAsett if there is no ParentAssetID or show the Parent.AsseCD if it is.

This needs to be on the DAC as it may be used for generic inquiries and reports etc.

Here are my attributes below for the field

```
[PXInt]
[PXParent(typeof(Select<FixedAsset, Where<FixedAsset.assetID, Equal<Current<FixedAsset.parentAssetID>>>>))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="ParentAssetID", IsReadOnly = true)]
[PXFormula(typeof(Switch<
    Case<Where<FixedAsset.parentAssetID, Equal<Null>>, FixedAsset.assetCD,
    Case<Where<FixedAsset.parentAssetID, NotEqual<Null>>, Parent<FixedAsset.assetCD>>>>))]
```

So the first line works fine, but when it gets into the second case I get a blank.  Am I using the Parent the correct way?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in FixedAsset the **ParentAssetID** field is decorated with the **PXSelector** attribute, you can achieve the desired result with a simpler formula utilizing **Selector** operator instead of **Parent**:

```
public class FixedAssetExt : PXCacheExtension<FixedAsset>
{
    public abstract class parentAssetCD : IBqlField { }

    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Parent Asset ID", Enabled = false)]
    [PXFormula(typeof(Switch<
        Case<Where<FixedAsset.parentAssetID, IsNotNull>, Selector<FixedAsset.parentAssetID, FixedAsset.assetCD>>,
        FixedAsset.assetCD>))]
    public string ParentAssetCD { get; set; }
}
```